# Spark pushdown predicate query in Databricks is not working

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, mssql-jdbc

When using [Apache Spark connector for SQL Server and Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15), I get the following error on the last line of the code below where I am using `Apache Spark pushdown predicate`. I'm trying to mimic the following [example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases#python-example) documentation.

**Error**:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

**Question**: What may be a cause of the error and how can we fix it?

**Goal**: is to right an SQL query result from Azure SQL Db to a `.csv` file using Spark Dataframe and [SQL JDBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases#python-example).

```
server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://myAzure-ManagedInstance.database.windows.net"

database_name = "myAzureDb"
jdbcUrl = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"

connectionProperties = {
  "user" : "mySQLUsername,
  "password" : "mySQLPassword,
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

pushdown_query = "(SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Customers)"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be a typing mistake in your code.

In `connectionProperties`, you need to add double quotes to `mySQLUsername` and `mySQLPassword`

```
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : "mySQLUsername",
  "password" : "mySQLPassword",
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
```